# Get rid of unnecessary spaces when merging columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get rid of the unnecessary spaces when merging columns.

As you can see from this example, there are some leading spaces and some cases where I have 2 spaces between words:

```
create table #202002101
            (RowId smallint,
             Value1 varchar(30),
             Value2 varchar(30),
             Value3 varchar(30))

insert into #202002101
            (RowId, Value1, Value2, Value3)
    values (1 , null , 'Truck', 'Tractor'),
           (2 , 'Car' , 'Tractor','Truck'),
           (3 , 'Bike' ,null,'Truck')

select  Value1,
        Value2,
        Value3,
        concat(Value1, ' ', Value2, ' ', Value3) as 'Merged'
from #202002101;
```

1. In the first row there is a leading space
2. The second row is OK
3. The third row has 2 spaces between words

Comment: You should be able to wrap your concat in a combination of trim() for the leading space and replace() for the double spaces.

Comment: This seemed to solve the problem:

rtrim((ltrim(replace (concat(Value1, ' ', Value2, ' ', Value3), '  ', ' '))))

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or later, you may use the [`CONCAT_WS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```sql
SELECT
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', Value1, Value2, Value3) as 'Merged'
from #202002101;
```